# Is the worm brain understood?

Tags: neuroscience

Is the relationship between worm (C. elegans nematode or any worm) behavior and the worm brain understood? Is the learning technology within the worm brain understood? If so, what's a summary of the mathematical processes and biological implementations used? If not, what is the impediment to understanding?

Comment: Hi! This is an interesting question but you might have more success if you narrow it down to a specific question about worm or C. elegans brain function. It's also helpful to show you've done some research by summarizing what you already know so that answerers know where to begin with an explanation.

Comment: "Understood" is also incredibly broad and nearly impossible to actually obtain: you can read about the Dunning-Kruger effect. Or [this image](https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_800_800/AAEAAQAAAAAAAATtAAAAJDQzNTE4OWUzLTNjZDUtNDkyNS04OGYzLTQzZTkyYTE0ZjViMA.jpg), which I happened to find just now unsourced on a LinkedIn blog but it is definitely not the original, there are dozens and dozens of variants on the same idea.